# How to create low pass filter to remove the signal greater than 40pi using FDA/filterDesigner tools on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I am designing a filter to remove the unwanted signal in my D(w). The intention is to remove the signal at 4960pi and 5040pi (only w=±40pi is needed). So I use the built-in filter designer tool to remove the signal. Due to its shorter transition band, I decided to use Chebyshev (Butterworth is also ok). However, the matlab script has the following error. Nothing was being plotted on the graph too.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3n7n.png

This is the specification for my Chebyshev filter.
[image]

Signal D(w) has some noise, only the impulse at 40pi is needed. So LPF will suit in this case, but the output has some issue.

[image]

This is my script including the previous noise (introduced during modulation and demodulation processes). Any guidance is much appreciated.

%create symbolic functions x, a, b, c, d, e, f_c with independent variable t
syms x(t) a(t) h(t) b(t) c(t) d(t) e f_c(t) f_c1(t) f_c2(t) t tau

```
%create symbolic functions A, B, C, D, and E with independent variable w
syms A(w) B(w) C(w) D(w) E(w) w

x(t) = cos(100*pi*t);
a(t) = x(0.4*t);
h(t) = dirac(t-0.02);
b(t) = int(a(tau)*h(t-tau), 'tau', -inf, inf);

f_c(t) = 10*cos(2500*pi*t);
f_c1(t) = f_c(t);
f_c2(t) = f_c(t);

c(t) = b(t)*f_c1(t);
d(t) = c(t)*f_c2(t);

figure

subplot (3,1,1)
fplot(a(t))
xlim([-0.05 0.05]),ylim([-1.5 1.5])
title ('Time domain of signal a(t)')
xlabel('Time, t')
ylabel('Amplitude, a(t)')
grid on

A(w) = fourier(a(t), w);
w = -60*pi:0.1*pi:60*pi;
subsA = A(w);
% Replace Inf value with suitable value
idx = subsA == Inf;
subsA(idx) = pi; % choose suitable value from the expression of fourier transform.
subplot (3,1,2)
plot(w,real(subsA));
ylim([0 4])
title ('Frequency domain of signal A(\omega)')
ylabel("\Re(A(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");
xticks(-40*pi:20*pi:40*pi);
xticklabels({'-40\pi', '-20\pi', '0', '20\pi', '40\pi'})

subplot (3,1,3)
plot(w, angle(A(w)))
title ('Phase spectrum of signal A(\omega)')
ylabel("\angle(A(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");


figure

subplot(3,1,1)
fplot(b(t))
xlim([-0.05 0.05]),ylim([-1.5 1.5])
title ('Time domain of signal b(t)')
xlabel('Time, t')
ylabel('Amplitude, b(t)')
grid on

syms B w
B(w) = fourier(b(t), w);
w = -60*pi:0.1*pi:60*pi;
subsB = B(w);
% Replace Inf value with suitable value
idx = abs(subsB) == Inf;
subsB(idx) = pi; % choose suitable value from the expression of fourier transform.
subplot (3,1,2)
plot(w,real(subsB));
ylim([0 4])
title ('Frequency domain of signal B(\omega)')
ylabel("\Re(B(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");
xticks(-40*pi:20*pi:40*pi);
xticklabels({'-40\pi', '-20\pi', '0', '20\pi', '40\pi'})

subplot (3,1,3)
plot(w, angle(B(w)))
ylim([-4 4])
title ('Phase spectrum of signal B(\omega)')
ylabel("\angle(B(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");

figure

subplot(3,1,1)
fplot(c(t))
xlim([-0.05 0.05]),ylim([-12 12])
title ('Time domain of signal c(t)')
xlabel('Time, t')
ylabel('Amplitude, c(t)')
grid on

syms C w
C(w) = fourier(c(t), w);
%simplify(C(w))
w = -2800*pi:20*pi:2800*pi;
subsC = C(w);
subsC
% Replace Inf value with suitable value
idx = abs(subsC) == Inf;
idx
subsC(idx) = pi; % choose suitable value from the expression of fourier transform.
subplot (3,1,2)
plot(w,real(5*subsC));
%testing = subsC
ylim([0 20])
title ('Frequency domain of signal C(\omega)')
ylabel("\Re(C(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");


subplot (3,1,3)
plot(w, angle(C(w)))
ylim([-4 4])
title ('Phase spectrum of signal C(\omega)')
ylabel("\angle(C(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");


figure 

subplot(3,1,1)
fplot(d(t))
xlim([-0.1 0.1]),ylim([-110 110])
title ('Time domain of signal d(t)')
xlabel('Time, t')
ylabel('Amplitude, d(t)')
grid on

syms D w
D(w) = fourier(d(t), w);
w = -5050*pi:10*pi:5050*pi;
%simplify(D(w))
subsD = D(w);
%D(w)
% Replace Inf value with suitable value
idx = abs(subsD) == Inf;
subsD(idx) = pi; % choose suitable value from the expression of fourier transform.
subplot (3,1,2)
plot(w,real(25*subsD));
ylim([0 160])
title ('Frequency domain of signal D(\omega)')
ylabel("\Re(D(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");

subplot (3,1,3)
plot(w, angle(D(w)))
ylim([-4 4])
title ('Phase spectrum of signal D(\omega)')
ylabel("\angle(D(\omega))");
xlabel("\omega");

figure

LPF_fil = lpf;
E = filter(LPF_fil, D);
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(w, E)

% fc = 150000;
% fs = 1000000;
% [e_mag,e_ang] = butter(6,fc/(fs/2));
% freqz(e_mag,e_ang)
% e = filter(e_mag,e_ang,d);
% eF=fftshift(fft(e));
% eFm=abs(eF);
% eFa=angle(eF);
% eFa(abs(eF)<T)=0;
```

Comment: The first question which comes to my mind is, why are you using symbolic math when you are trying to apply a discrete filter? Looking at your error, it seems that it is exactly your problem, you filter is expecting a numeric input.

Comment: @Irreducible, so how do you solve the problem?

Comment: Just dont use the symbolic approach? Have you tried to google "how to filter with matlab", or even have a look on the matlab help regarding filtering e.g.: [filtering-data](https://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/filtering-data-with-signal-processing-toolbox.html).